# What to do about gap between tile and tub

Tags: shower, tile, gap

This is my first shower tiling project and the tub was not level at all. To make sure my tiles were level I left a gap between the first row and the tub on one side (see picture). The gap is 1/2” at its widest. I’m wondering what you would suggest for finishing this project up. Should I attempt to simply fill the gap with white caulk or should I buy some sort of cover?

I won’t re-do this now but for the future should I have done this project differently? Perhaps cut my first row on an angle and left it closer to the top of the tub?

[image]

Comment: If you caulk it, do it with a full tub of water. That way when it's empty, it will compress the caulk. If you caulk it while it's empty, when you fill it with water, the weight will pull the caulk apart.

Comment: The tub is pitched the wrong way.  You  had a chance to fix that maybe. Not sure if floor is done and could not.  Or cut the tile to fit to close gap,  seems if 3/8 was cut off valve end would have  closed gap down.  Try to get the best caulking you can..No matter what in time it will discolor or get mold. just try to keep dry and clean to prolong it.  Dry the low corner with a towel so water does not stand for long periods of time .

Comment: Should've started the tile at the gapped end (the lower point) and trim the tiles to fit so the top of the first row is level but the bottoms meet the tub.  I made a similar mistake my first time tiling my tub area.

Answer (score 1):

I have always found the top surface ie edge is always level and the slope is built into the shape of the shower base.

However, one neat solution for your gap is to fit a cornice molding ie a triangular tile usually the same length as the side of the tiles all around the edge and it will cover the gap much neater than filling it with caulk, but you could do that anyway for peace of mind against insidious leaks.

See
[cornice tile](https://images.app.goo.gl/3UJ7AgYNPEkc7oyc7)

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I think I’ll try the cornice molding if it’ll hold up better in the long run! It’s an old house I think the floor up here is just slanted so the tub on top of it is slanted as well. Tbh I didn’t even notice until I had my laser level on the wall to start tiling.